# Is it possible to reuse code from atlassian's stash *.soy

Tags: plugins, bitbucket-server, soy-templates

Is it possible to reuse code from atlassian's stash *.soy?

I need to add a button on the login page of Stash's `login.soy`.
After some research I have come to know that we can rewrite `.soy` using soyTemplateRenderer but no luck.

Can you explain me how we rewrite or change the template of Stash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use their existing template, but you can do something like a [Web Item Plugin Module](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/plugin-modules/web-item-plugin-module) and specify the [context](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/web-resource-contexts.html) to be something like `stash.page.login`.